# Tangent cone: don't understand

Tags: convex-analysis, tangent-spaces, convex-cone

A cone is a set that is closed under multiplication by positive scalars. The tangent
cone of $f$ at $x$ is defined as the set of descent directions of $f$
at $x$
$$\mathcal{T}_f(\boldsymbol{x})=\{\boldsymbol{u}\in\mathbb{R}^n: f(\boldsymbol{x}+t\cdot\boldsymbol{u})\le f(\boldsymbol{x}) \ \text{for some}\ t>0 \}$$.

The problem is, how can I get the tangent cone of $f(\boldsymbol{x})=||\boldsymbol{x}||_1$ at point $\boldsymbol{x}=(1,0)$?

[image: enter image]

Adding: the picture of $f(\boldsymbol{x})=||\boldsymbol{x}||_1$ is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2j64y.png)

I think I get a new understanding of tangent cone, is the tangent cone of $y=|x|$ at $(0,0)$ as the following picture?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uGEy.jpg)

Comment: If you draw the level set of $f$ at $(1,0)$ it is not hard to guess the set of descent directions from the picture.

Comment: @copper.hat sorry for the typo.

Comment: @copper.hat Can you give me some visualized illustration?

Comment: $f((1,0)) = 1$ and the level set of $f$ for the value $1$ is $\{ x | |x_1|+|x_2| \le 1 \}$. This is a diamond centred ot the origin. Plot the point $(1,0)$ on this and look for directions from this point that go 'in' to the diamond or run parallel to the side. These are your descent directions.